# Boosting AND Bagging Trees (XGBoost, LightGBM)

Tags: cart, boosting, bagging

There are many blog posts, YouTube videos, etc. about the ideas of **bagging** *or* **boosting** trees. My general understanding is that the pseudo code for each is:

**Bagging:**

1. Take N random samples of x% of the samples and y% of the features
2. Fit your model (e.g., decision tree) on each of N
3. Predict with each N
4. Average the predictions to get the final prediction

**Boosting:**

1. Fit your model (e.g., decision tree) to your data
2. Get the residuals
3. Fit your model to the residuals
4. Go to 2 for N boosting rounds
5. The final prediction is a weighted sum of the sequential predictors.

I'll take any clarifications to my understanding above, but my intended question is as follows:

Both XGBoost and LightGBM have params that allow for bagging. The application is not Bagging *OR* Boosting (which is what every blog post talks about), but Bagging *AND* Boosting. **What is the pseudo code for where and when the combined bagging and boosting takes place?**

I expected it to be "Bagged Boosted Trees", but it seems it is "Boosted Bagged Trees". The difference seems substantial.

**Bagged Boosted Trees:**

1. Take N random samples of x% of the samples and y% of the features
2. Fit Boosted trees on each of the N samples
3. Predict with each N
4. Average the predictions to get the final prediction

This seems like the best way to do it. After all, the risk in boosting is overfitting and the primary benefit of bagging is to reduce overfitting; bagging a bunch of boosted models seems like a great idea.

However, from looking through, for example the `scikit-learn` [gradient_boosting.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py#L1122) (which does sample bagging, but not random feature selection), and cobbling together some small nuggets across posts about LightGBM and XGBoost, it looks like XGBoost and LightGBM work as follows:

**Boosted Bagged Trees:**

1. Fit a decision tree to your data
2. For i in N boosting rounds:

   - Get the residuals
   - if i mod bag_frequency == 0 (i.e., bag every 5 rounds):

     - Take a single random sample of x% of the samples and y% of the features; use this random sample going forward
   - fit tree to the residuals
3. The final prediction is a weighted sum of the sequential predictors.

Please correct my understanding here and fill in the details. Boosted Bagged Tree (with just 1 random tree per bag_frequency) doesn't seem as powerful as Bagged Boosted Tree.

Comment: +1 for an interesting and very well-formulated question. And welcome to the site.

Comment: you need a "compute the error" for your boosting.  Done wrong that falls apart.  The weights are critical for adaboost.  It isn't a raw residual. ... We aren't talking about stochastic gradient as necessary in boosting, though it speeds things up.

Comment: Here is the boosted-bagged.  Instead of a new tree for each series-step you get a new forest with average output.  Eugene Tuv and Kari Torkkola.  http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/tuv09a/tuv09a.pdf

Comment: the bagged boosted is going to make a forest of series ensembles, and take the average output.  It might engage the over-fitting that a series(boosted) ensemble can make, and give a more robust output, but the gain isn't going to be huge.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Bagging:
>   Take N random samples of x% of the samples and y% of the Features

Instances are repeatedly sub-sampled in **Bagging**, but not Features. (*RandomForests*, *XGBoost* and *CatBoost* do both):

```
Given dataset D of size N.
For m in n_models:
    Create new dataset D_i of size N by sampling with replacement from D.
    Train model on D_i (and then predict)
Combine predictions with equal weight
```

---

Include an initialization step in your **Boosting** pseudo code to get rid of redundancy:

```
Init data with equal weights (1/N).
For m in n_model:
    Train model on weighted data (and then predict)
    Update weights according to misclassification rate.
    Renormalize weights
Combine confidence weighted predictions
```

---

**Bagged Boosted Trees** (as you call it) is certainly a reasonable Approach, but different from *XGBoost* or *CatBoost*:

```
Given dataset D of size N.
For m in n_models:
    Create new dataset D_i of size N by sampling with replacement from D.
    (Insert Boosting pseudo code here (on D_i))
Combine predictions with equal weight
```

---

*XGBoost* and *CatBoost* are both based on **Boosting** and use the entire training data. They also implement bagging by subsampling once in every boosting Iteration:

```
Init data with equal weights (1/N).
For m in n_model:
    Train model on weighted bootstrap sample (and then predict)
    Update weights according to misclassification rate.
    Renormalize weights
Combine confidence weighted predictions
```

If you want to stick to "fit model to residuals", then this would be equivalent to "fit model to residuals of data in **bootstrap sample**".

---

**Further Remarks**:

There is no "*best way to do it*" as you suggest (no free lunch theorem). "Bagged Boosted Trees" might outperform XGBoost on certain data sets.

> Take a single random sample of x% of the samples

This line is confusing. Where did you get this from?

> if i mod bag_frequency == 0 (i.e., bag every 5 rounds):

This should not be mentioned in your pseudo code. Especially when there are other more important parameters left out (like *learning rate* in boosting).

Comment: (+1) Nice answer! To clarify: is the OP incorrect in stating "*Both XGBoost and LightGBM have params that allow for bagging*"?

Comment: Both allow for bagging: *bagging_fraction* in *LightGBM* and *subsample* in *XGBoost*. Not sure, why I referred to CatBoost the whole time. But they all work the same way in regards to the question.

Comment: My mistake, I missed the line in your answer that mentions that. Could you explain "*subsampling once in every boosting Iteration*"? Do you mean that in each boosting iteration, many subsamples are taken, trees are fit to each subsample, and then the misclassification rate is calculated based on the bagged trees, and finally weights updated? If so, could you clarify this in your pseudocode?

Comment: Not many sub-samples are drawn, just one: Instead of fitting the model to all weighted instances, the model is trained on a bootstrap sample.

Comment: Regarding "Take a single random sample of x% of the samples"; better would be "take a single sample of x% of the rows". I got that from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py#L1190).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the XGBoost method? For example, I have further learned details of `scikit-learn` tree bagging:

Given dataset D of size N.
For m in n_models: Create new dataset D_i of size N by sampling with replacement from D;  Train tree model on D_i and *at each split* choose random features; (and then predict); Combine predictions with equal weight.

Comment: yes, scikit-learn Bagging also supports feature sampling (making it a RandomForest if based on trees). Elaborate on XGBoost or RandomForests? what exactly is unclear